# Is that good to have both SDD point to root

Tags: mount, ssd

My ubuntu:

```
 ~# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
 NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
 sda                       223.6G
 |-sda1  linux_raid_member   953M            NC-PH-0456-19:0
 | `-md0 ext4                953M /boot
 |-sda2  linux_raid_member    32G            NC-PH-0456-19:1
 | `-md1 swap                 32G [SWAP]
 `-sda3  linux_raid_member 190.7G            NC-PH-0456-19:2
   `-md2 ext4              190.7G /
 sdb                       223.6G
 |-sdb1  linux_raid_member   953M            NC-PH-0456-19:0
 | `-md0 ext4                953M /boot
 |-sdb2  linux_raid_member    32G            NC-PH-0456-19:1
 | `-md1 swap                 32G [SWAP]
 `-sdb3  linux_raid_member 190.7G            NC-PH-0456-19:2
   `-md2 ext4              190.7G /
```

Our websites is store in /var/www while backups go to /var/backups. So I wonder if sda die, then is my data and backups safe ?

On windows, you know.. I would  store working things on C: and backups on D: . I am pretty newbie to Un

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important things first:

Backups should always be stored in another place than the system they were created from.
Transfer them to your local box or a backup space or even some cloud storage like box.com or Dropbox or similar.

Now to the discs:

Both discs are in a raid setup. This allows the system to work even if one of the discs fails. It is not a backup, though. Performance is not enhanced due to raid level 1 being used.
If the file system gets corrupted it is corrupted on both discs. So make sure you're backups are stored elsewhere.